# Fiware for data collection from IOT devices

Tags: fiware, iot, fiware-orion

I am to design an IOT platform which should collect sensor data from tens of thousands of sources or more. Process this data in different ways and present the user with interactive dashboards which allow the user to drill down through the aggregate information down to the specific device level. Also support the case where the user might ask for live information from that specific device.

I have ideas which tools I could use for data stream distributed processing but not much about how to interface with IOT devices. And that's why I started looking into FIWARE.

Reading through FIWARE site, different FIWARE architecture documents, GE specific documentation etc. and trying to answer my own design architecture questions. The abundance of available information is confusing to say the least.
**I think that my main difficulty at the moment is to map from the architecture as it is described [here](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Internet_of_Things_(IoT)_Services_Enablement_Architecture) to the actual available implementation components.**

**Question:**
If I am to use FIWARE GEis as a device proxy which receives data from devices and forwards to the realtime processing pipeline, which GEis should I use? And which specific implementations?

Answer (score -1):

For IoT, there are a suite of tools that I use in my solutions.

**Message Passing**: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-hub/

**Hot Data:** SQL Azure

**Archived Data:** Blob Storage (migrating to Data Lake)

**Machine Learning:** https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/machine-learning/

**Charts/Rendering:** https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/

**Data Pipelining:**  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/

**Real Time Analysis:**  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/stream-analytics/

Every single one of these tools integrate very well and can be used to drive real time streaming charts and intelligence as well as your traditional daily/weekly reports.  Occasionally I need to run ad-hoc queries and will stand up a Hadoop cluster on top of the Blob Storage.  When Azure Data Lake Hits GA, Azure Data Lake Analytics with U-SQL will become my go-to ad-hoc query.

The Azure IoT Hub specifically allows for very simple set up and coding for devices, 1 line of code and also enables bi-directional communication device to device, device to cloud and cloud to device.  Coupled with the massive scale it allows, this has become my go-to IoT message passing platform and I use in every solution now.

Microsoft has pushed out what is called the "IoT Suite", which I am finding very easy to roll out for these scenarios. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/internet-of-things/azure-iot-suite.aspx?WT.srch=1&WT.mc_ID=SEM_7Ecxw3zD

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi David, I am only looking into open and open source technologies at the moment.